# Converting mm/dd/yyyy date column string to yyyy-mm-dd in Databricks SQL

Tags: sql, data-analysis, databricks-sql

I am trying to convert a date column which is in string type to date type in yyyy-mm-dd format but I am getting null as output in databricks SQL.
I tried `date(CAST(date_col as timestamp))` also I tried `date(date_col)` both are giving `null`

**sample Column**

[image]

**Output required**

[image]

Comment: Use a proper date type instead of trying to cover up the bad design. Dates are binary values in all the tagged databases. They have no format. Use the correct type instead of trying to guess string formats. Right now you have *no* idea what the format of each *string* is, just guesses. You have no idea what `4/7/2023` means. You only know what `4/26/2023` is *not*.

Comment: Bugs like this have serious real-life consequences. They're behind the $100K water bills you hear about in the news, or even more serious consequences like [The Spanish family wrongly accused of child pornography due to a mistake reading a date](https://english.elpais.com/spanish_news/2020-09-08/the-spanish-family-wrongly-accused-of-child-pornography-due-to-a-mistake-reading-a-date.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be looking for [`to_date()` in databricks sql](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/functions/to_date.html), which turns a string to a date:

```
select t.*,
    to_date(date_col, 'M/d/yyyy') new_date_col
from mytable t
```

Consider adapting the format specifier for your actual dataset; this assumes strings like `'4/26/2023'` or `'4/1/2023'`.